# CMake :Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, qt-creator

I am new to cmake. I am trying to build opencv using cmake 3.7.2 (64 bit)to be used in Qt.
I am working on a windows 10 64 bit system.
I have followed the steps given in the link:
https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows

As per the instructions I installed Qt-Qt5.9-MingGW 5.3.0 32 bit.

The path for MinGW is also set to C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin.

The link above shows the following instructions:

[Compiling OpenCV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHxFd.jpg)

When I followed the instructions for building opencv I got the following error after clicking "Configure"

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHZAa.jpg)

It would be good if someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: An easier way to get this would be to use msys2 to install mingw and opencv for you using its package manager pacman.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect error message to be in the **question post**  itself, not *linked* as *image*. Also, make sure that you paste the **first error message**, not the plain "Error in configuration process" which occurs in case of any fail. Please, read [ask] and [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: When you were configuring I expect you did not do all of these Set lines `Set QT_MAKE_EXECUTABLE to D:\Qt\5.9\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe` in cmake-gui

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks a lot for your response. It worked now. I set Set QT_MAKE_EXECUTABLE to D:\Qt\5.9\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe in cmake-gui. You may post it as an answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed the instruction to set `QT_MAKE_EXECUTABLE` and other variables in cmake-gui. The instructions from the https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows documentation state this:

> Set QT_MAKE_EXECUTABLE to D:\Qt\5.9\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe
> Set Qt5Concurrent_DIR to D:\Qt\5.9\mingw53_32\lib\cmake\Qt5Concurrent
> Set Qt5Core_DIR to D:\Qt\5.9\mingw53_32\lib\cmake\Qt5Core
> Set Qt5Gui_DIR to D:\Qt\5.9\mingw53_32\lib\cmake\Qt5Gui
> Set Qt5Test_DIR to D:\Qt\5.9\mingw53_32\lib\cmake\Qt5Test
> Set Qt5Widgets_DIR to D:\Qt\5.9\mingw53_32\lib\cmake\Qt5Widgets
> Set Qt5OpenGL_DIR to D:\Qt\5.9\mingw53_32\lib\cmake\Qt5OpenGL
> Set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to Release or RelWithDebInfo
> Set OPENCV_VS_VERSIONINFO_SKIP=1

You do these inside cmake-gui